# Flask: How to filter and display different CRUD tables with pagination?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, crud

In my Flask application, I have 10+ CRUD tables that I want to display one at a time using a Select dropdown. I have found and followed a lot of tutorials that helped me out in implementing one single CRUD table, but I haven't found a solution when it comes to the multiple tables.

In my current solution, I have managed to only make filtering and displaying tables work, but I am facing issues with the rest of the functionality like,

- Unable to work the pagination, for any table other than default.
- Setting up default table to be displayed
- Editing/Deleting for specific tables
- Rerouting back to the same table after editing/deleting

At this point, I had to hard code the table names in my code, but I want this all to be dynamic. How can I make it all work dynamically?

[image]

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from forms import Dropdown_Form

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "Secret Key"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///site.db"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Table_A(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = db.Column(db.Integer)
    name = db.Column(db.String(300))

    def __init__(self, code, name):
        self.code = code
        self.name = name


class Table_B(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = db.Column(db.Integer)
    name = db.Column(db.String(300))

    def __init__(self, code, name):
        self.code = code
        self.name = name


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    form = Dropdown_Form()

    page = request.args.get("page", 1, type=int)
    table = Table_A.query.paginate(page=page, per_page=5)

    if request.method == "POST":
        table = globals()[request.form.get("table_name")]

        page = request.args.get("page", 1, type=int)
        table = table.query.paginate(page=page, per_page=5)
        return render_template("index.html", form=form, table=table)

    return render_template("index.html", form=form, table=table)


@app.route("/insert", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def insert():

    if request.method == "POST":

        code = request.form.get("code")
        name = request.form.get("name")
        my_data = Table_B(code, name)

        db.session.add(my_data)
        db.session.commit()

        flash("Data inserted successfully.")

        return redirect(url_for("index"))


@app.route("/update", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def update():

    if request.method == "POST":

        my_data = Table_B.query.get(request.form.get("id"))

        my_data.code = request.form.get("code")
        my_data.name = request.form.get("name")

        db.session.commit()
        flash("Data updated successfully.")

        return redirect(url_for("index"))


@app.route("/delete/<id>/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def delete(id):

    my_data = Table_B.query.get(id)
    db.session.delete(my_data)
    db.session.commit()
    flash("Data deleted successfully.")

    return redirect(url_for("index"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SelectField, SubmitField #, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField

class Dropdown_Form(FlaskForm):
    table_name = SelectField("Table Name", choices=[("Table_A","Table A"), ("Table_B", "Table B")])
    submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

**templates\base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
 
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    

</body>
</html>
```

**templates\index.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% block title %} Home {% endblock %} 
{% block body %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-4 mb-4">
    <div class="col md-12">
      <div class="content-section">

        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Manage Tables</legend>

        <form method="POST" action="">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3">
                    {{ form.table_name(class="form-control form-select form-control-sm") }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block") }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <hr>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col mt-2 mb-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-left" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">Add Data</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
            <thead class="table-light">
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

          {% for row in table.items %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.code }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
                <td>
                <a href="/update/{{row.id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaledit{{row.id}}">Edit</a>
                <a href="/delete/{{row.id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure To Delete?')">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <!-- Modal Edit Employee-->
            <div id="modaledit{{row.id}}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Update Information</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="{{url_for('update')}}" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Code:</label>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{row.id}}" />
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="code" value="{{row.code}}" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{row.name}}"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                            Update
                        </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </table>

        {% for page in table.iter_pages() %}
            {% if page %}
                {% if table.page == page %}
                    <a class="btn btn-primary mb-4" href="{{ url_for('index', table_name='Table_A', page=page) }}">{{ page }}</a>
                {% else %}
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-4" href="{{ url_for('index', table_name='Table_A', page=page) }}">{{ page }}</a>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

      </div>

      <!-- Modal Add Employee-->
      <div id="mymodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title">Add Data</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="POST" action="{{url_for('insert')}}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Code:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="code" required="1"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required="1"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                            Add Data
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
                          Close
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you making a todo list app. if you want to implement things like searching for something in the table , pagination , or show these much entries then you can use [datatables](https://datatables.net/). it is a jquery library which will handle these functionalities.

Go and follow the instructions. It is super easy.